# Jquery dialog layout

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a simple jquery UI dialog which is triggered by a button.

```
function OpenGeneratePINsDialog() {
$("#generatePinsDialog").dialog('open');
```

}

What I want is to display numbers next the labels. Now it is not displayed in-block.

```
<div id="generateDialog" title="Generate New">
<label style="display:inline-block; width:200px;">The number generated: </label><div id="numberGenerated">1</div>
<br />
<label style="display:inline-block; width:200px;">ID+PIN</label><div id="combinationIDPIN">2</div>
<br />
<label style="display:inline-block; width:200px;">Same as ID</label><div id="SameWithID">3</div>
```

The image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use div, div are by default setted to `display:block;`

Set it to inline-block and you are just fine.

```
<div id="numberGenerated" style="display:inline-block;">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline element for the number, like a "span".

```
<span id="numberGenerated">1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="generateDialog" title="Generate New" class="mystyle">
<label>The number generated: </label><div id="numberGenerated">1</div>
<br />
<label>ID+PIN</label><div id="combinationIDPIN">2</div>
<br />
<label>Same as ID</label><div id="SameWithID">3</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.mystyle label, .mystyle div {
  display:inline-block;
}

.mystyle label {
  width:200px; /* or whatever size you want them */
}
```